# Is there a Ubuntu sanity check?

Tags: package-management, files

Is there a standard procedure to 'unit test' an Ubuntu system against the deb packages?

Assume, a system has ubuntu-desktop installed according to the package manager. Can I find out, whether the file system has all the files in ubuntu-desktop and dependencies?

related question: [Find packages with corrupted files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57682/find-and-reinstall-packages-with-corrupted-files-without-breaking-anything)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For the most part, deb packages come with a md5 file containing signatures of all files in the package. These files are located at `/var/lib/dpkg/info/$pkg.md5sums`.

To simplify the periodic check of all installed packages, the `debsums` package can be of help. Install it, clean the cache with:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

then run `sudo debsums_init` to generate md5 sums for packages that do not provide them (the packages are downloaded to generate such sums).

Next, edit the file `/etc/default/debsums` and set `CRON_CHECK=weekly` to configure a cron weekly job for the check of debsums.

You can run the check manually with the command:

```
sudo debsums -cs
```

Regarding the integrity of the dependencies, I suppose that the command:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

should signal and try to resolve any problem it finds relative to installed packages, but the Debian/Ubuntu package management system is a very complex object, and could be very difficult to find and resolve its problems.

Comment: If `sudo debsums -cs` says nothing, does it mean that everything alright ?

Comment: `sudo apt-get -f install` gives "post-installation script subprocess returned error" about. "[some file] not found". What to do?

Comment: if there is an error, reinstall the package:  `dpkg --search /some/fqpn/some.file;  apt-get --reinstall install package;`