# Started to delete /usr/share by mistake: what to do now?

Tags: rm

In Ubuntu 16.04, I ran by mistake `sudo rm -rf /usr/share`. I know how stupid that is (I wanted to remove `/usr/share/somefolder` that had been installed as root and got distracted). I interrupted it after about 5 seconds. I can already see some strange things: some text is not displaying on askubuntu.SE in firefox, when I open a terminal I get `/etc/zsh/zshrc:111: compinit: function definition file not found`, autocompletion returns an error, etc.

My question is: what should I do now?

**Edit** I install `debsums` and followed the steps in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/57728/306960) to [Is there a Ubuntu sanity check?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57704/is-there-a-ubuntu-sanity-check). With the command `sudo debsums -cs`, I could see that a lot of things where broken. However, I could not fix that other than by reinstalling (see my more detailed answer).

Comment: Many critical system files are (were) in /usr/share. A simple method is to boot from a LiveUSB, backup your data, and then reinstall.

Comment: I've reopened your post. Sorry for the wait.

Comment: @Seth Thank you. I must say I was very surprised, but all is good now.

Answer (score 0):

Well boot Linux from USB drive and try `extundelete`
Tool is for recovering deleted files from unmounted partition to mounted one.

```
$ extundelete /dev/sdaX --restore-all
```

OR

`$ extundelete /dev/sdaX --restore-directory /path/to/dir`

> For more info about extundelete check: http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

What I finally did was to reinstall Ubuntu without formatting the partition, so that all my documents and some programs were preserved.

1. Backup data
2. Boot on live USB (actually I used a Linux Mint 18.3)
3. In the destination prompt, choose "other choices" (or something similar) and select the partition with the faulty Ubuntu
4. Select / as mount point (I don't know if that is required)
5. Finalise the installation

This way I now have a clean installation with all my previous documents, settings, etc.