# Locate all modified system config files

Tags: upgrade, filesystem, backup

I recently upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04... which seems to be a "fubar" situation.  It appears that I will need to do a complete fresh install of 20.04 to get my system working again, due to some mysterious freezing issues.

During the upgrade process, Ubuntu was able to recognize all of my customized system files, and asked me if I wanted to keep them or replace them.

How do they do this?  Is there any other method I can use to locate those same files (so as to back them up)?

Example of files edited by me within the system folder that I would like to backup before a full system reinstall:

sudoers
my.cnf
mysql.cnf.d
apache2 virtualhost files
crontab

what terminal command will identify any file modified by me so that I may make a backup?

Comment: There is no need for that if you can not figure this out: install without formatting and the system will not touch user settings and user files. Mind that the best method is to boot from a live session and mount the partitions and then copy files over to an external disk. Where those files are is impossible to answer... likely those are in /home/$USER/ but... you put them somewhere so you will be the one to answer that question ;-)

Comment: The point is to do a completely fresh install and wipeout everything that could be causing an error.  I posted the question to save some time on re-doing my configs.  I already have good ~/ backups

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a Ubuntu sanity check?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57704/is-there-a-ubuntu-sanity-check)

Comment: Nope... I am specifically looking for system files that I edited... not corrupted files