# Reinstall Ubuntu to its default state, without an installation medium like a DVD or USB?

Tags: system-installation, data-recovery

Having mucked up my system fairly... horridly, I just want to get my system back to a fresh install state, where I have absolutely no leftovers from my current state, including packages, configs, users, and so forth. Problem is, I just don't have a usb flash drive [etc] handy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find (and reinstall) packages with corrupted files (without breaking anything)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/57682/find-and-reinstall-packages-with-corrupted-files-without-breaking-anything)

Comment: Also look at [this script](http://dannyman.toldme.com/2010/05/05/ubuntu-reinstall-all-packages/).

Answer (score 1):

What about running this in terminal:

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`