# No dash, side bar after deleting hicolor theme!

Tags: unity-dash

I try to install new themes and icons. But I delete some unnecessary themes, I think I delete hicolor theme. After that some of icons are missing. I use unity --reset-icons command. And then reboot. And then no dash no side bar.
I try so much to fix issue in tty but no answer. 
What should I do now?
Thanks.

Comment: check the suggestions here http://askubuntu.com/questions/468204/no-panels-or-menus-after-upgrading-to-14-04/468431#468431

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find (and reinstall) packages with corrupted files (without breaking anything)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/57682/find-and-reinstall-packages-with-corrupted-files-without-breaking-anything)

Answer (score -1):

Try Hitting the Superkey (windows key) and search `Appearance` make sure that your "launcher Icon Size" is 48 then go to `Behaviour`and make sure "Auto Hide" is turned off.

Comment: I don't have dash and sidebar at all. So how can I search?!

Comment: Do you have a windows key? if you do just try hitting it, the dash opens right up.  I had the same problem and fixed it like that.

Comment: The dash not open. I try that before...

Comment: Hmm... I'm not really an expert so I don't know, sorry. @HosseinDibapour