# "Failed To Fetch" when installing KDE

Tags: apt, software-installation, kde

I'm trying to install KDE 5 on my Ubuntu 16.04 system as per the instructions in [this tutorial](http://www.tecmint.com/install-kde-plasma-5-in-linux/), but I'm getting the below error message when running `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`.

Is there something I can do to resolve this?

```
Need to get 682 kB/326 MB of archives.
After this operation, 1,272 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 
            gtk2-engines-oxygen amd64 1.4.6-1ubuntu1
  Temporary failure resolving 'ir.archive.ubuntu.com'
Get:2 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 
            libkf5sendlater5 amd64 4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1 [45.2 kB]
Get:3 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 
            libthreadweaver4 amd64 4:4.14.16-0ubuntu3 [46.6 kB]
Get:4 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 
            libfarstream-0.2-5 amd64 0.2.7-0ubuntu1 [192 kB]
Fetched 284 kB in 1min 9s (4,093 B/s)        
E: Failed to fetch http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/
            gtk2-engines-oxygen/gtk2-engines-oxygen_1.4.6-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  
            Temporary failure resolving 'ir.archive.ubuntu.com'

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or 
            try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: It says "temporary failure resolving '...'" - I'd just wait a few minutes or an hour or a day and try it again.

Comment: ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports is not even in that list. Have you tried sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop?

Comment: yes, i did it again, now it just unpacking  and selecting like this saysUnpacking ruby-minitest (5.8.4-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ruby-net-telnet

Comment: and ask me to report problem to developer

Comment: and now get this error Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/kaccounts-providers_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get update` before?

Answer (score 1):

You are having temporary difficulty reaching http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com I've found that one good way to resolve this problem is by opening Software And Updates. Choose Download from Other.

[image: SnU]

Choose Select best server

[image: SnU2]

You'll see this:

[image: SnU3]

Click Choose Server to select the recommended server

Comment: so what should i have to do then reinstall kde plasma

Comment: I would try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/57682/find-and-reinstall-packages-with-corrupted-files-without-breaking-anything after removing `ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports` from your sources.lst