# Gnome doesn't install on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gnome, kubuntu, kde

Yesterday I installed KDE Plasma on my Ubuntu 16.04.1 as I mentioned in this question ["Failed To Fetch" when installing KDE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/825947/failed-to-fetch-when-installing-kde) and had a black screen problem. I could log in with KDE and had mouse pointer but I couldn't do anything except log out. One of my friends on askubuntu chat suggested me to install a lighter desktop, I picked up Gnome 3 but unfortunately I don't know why it doesn't install. I ran `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop` and got this result:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 kde-telepathy-minimal : Depends: kde-config-telepathy-accounts (>= 15.04.0) but it is not going to be installed
 ubuntu-gnome-desktop : Depends: adwaita-icon-theme-full but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: brasero but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: dconf-editor but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: fonts-cantarell but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gdm3 but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gjs but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gnome-backgrounds but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gnome-color-manager but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gnome-contacts but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gnome-control-center but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gnome-documents but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gnome-logs but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gnome-online-accounts but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gnome-session but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gnome-settings-daemon but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gnome-shell but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gnome-shell-extensions but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gnome-sushi but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gnome-themes-standard but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gnome-tweak-tool but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: itstool but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libnss-myhostname but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: mutter but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: ssh-askpass-gnome but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: tracker but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: ubuntu-gnome-default-settings but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: yelp-tools but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: zsync but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: a11y-profile-manager
                        Recommends: deja-dup-backend-cloudfiles but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: deja-dup-backend-s3 but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: empathy but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: evolution but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: gnome-accessibility-profiles but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: gnome-getting-started-docs but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: gnome-music but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: gnome-photos but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: gnome-weather but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: ibus-pinyin
                        Recommends: mcp-account-manager-goa but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: numix-gtk-theme but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: plymouth-theme-ubuntu-gnome-logo but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: plymouth-theme-ubuntu-gnome-text but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: ppa-purge but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: telepathy-idle but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: ubuntu-gnome-wallpapers but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: xserver-xorg-legacy but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that KDE is only partially installed, so it is conflicting with GNOME and the package manager. First remove KDE. **Then** install GNOME 3. Please comment if you need more help.

Comment: I'd have suggested running `tasksel` but it has been known to act irrationally at times.