# Ubuntu 16.04 dual boot with windows 10 installation type screen has no options

Tags: boot, dual-boot, software-installation, xubuntu

I want to have a dual boot for windows 10 and ubuntu 16.04

During the installation and after the first screen:

[image: Preparing to install screen]
Then the installation type screen has no options:

[image: Installation type screen]

I select the '+' then I am asked for a username and password which I don't know.

I am stuck in this screen and I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: It's because your live-install session didn't recognized any disks at your computer and you "chose" install Ubuntu into boot USB stick.

Comment: @Redbob so what is the solution?

Comment: The first image you posted suggests Secure Boot is enabled. Enter BIOS setup and disable it, maybe it will enable disks to Ubuntu setup

Comment: Can you provide us the computer or motherboard model that you are using ? You are probably using a too recent SATA controller.

Comment: Did you also leave Windows fast start up on? http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions From Ubuntu live installer post this: `sudo parted -l`

Comment: @Redbob I disabled secure boot but then I cannot login to windows: I am  getting an PC ran into a problem and needs to restart. My motherboard details are :Dell Inc.     0WPMFG   .9H5BXJ2.CN744316B1032C.  A00

Comment: @oldfred I disabled fast startup but still I dont see any options at the installation type screen

Comment: If it is a Dell have you updated UEFI and SSD firmware? And changed from RAID or Intel SRT to AHCI in UEFI for drive settings. You may  need to install Windows AHCI driver first or reboot in recovery mode to install Windows AHCI driver. Dell with NVMe needs AHCI & boot option nvme_load=YES
https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/sln299303/loading-ubuntu-on-systems-using-pcie-m2-drives?lang=en
& http://askubuntu.com/questions/884991/ubuntu-16-10-dual-boot-error-grub-efi-amd64-signed-package-failed-to-install & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2353288