# How to install 17.04 on new 4 TB hard drive?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I am trying to install Ubuntu 17.04 from a USB stick created with UNETBOOTIN. I am installing to a Dell xps 8090. I just put a brand new 4TB drive in that I want to use for the install.

For some reason, during the install process, I see a warning that I am out of disk space. This was after I selected to do an erase and install to let the installer handle setting up the partitions. After the message indicating there was no more space on the drive displayed, a message would pop up saying the installer had crashed.

I am new to Ubuntu/Linux but I do have some experience with systems. I have tried various partitioning schemes based on what I have read online. Each time I get the 'out of space' message and it doesn't make any sense that I have a brand new 4TB drive and cannot get Ubuntu installed. I would appreciate any suggestions.

I have only the one 4 TB drive installed. No other systems are running on it. I do not intend to use dual-boot. `sudo fdisk -l` shows:

```
Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *          0 3100799 3100800  1.5G  0 Empty
/dev/sdb2       3006684 3011355    4672  2.3M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
```

It does look like I am trying to install to the USB for some reason - because the new drive isn't seen in fdisk? I will look at the link Sirajus included.

Sorry I noticed that I did not include all the fdisk -l output. Here it is:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.4 GiB, 1532116992 bytes, 2992416 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 3.7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 7C3D520C-5FD9-4F74-8F34-725AB0D1ABDC

Device          Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048       4095       2048    1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2        4096 7780610047 7780605952  3.6T Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  7780610048 7814035455   33425408   16G Linux swap




Disk /dev/sdb: 3.8 GiB, 4009754624 bytes, 7831552 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0d66cd15

Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *          0 3100799 3100800  1.5G  0 Empty
/dev/sdb2       3006684 3011355    4672  2.3M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: How many disks you have in your computer? Is there another system running on it? Do you intend to make a dual-boot? At live-usb session, open a terminal and type `sudo fdisk -l`, add the output at your question (not in comments), please.

Comment: You are probably trying to install to the USB.

Comment: Please read https://askubuntu.com/a/343352/529404

Comment: When I tried manual partitioning as described in link provided by Sirajus, I can see the new drive in 'Installation Type' window. I added a swap partition with no problem. Then I tried to add partition for / (root). A window came up (ubi-partman crashed) - failed with exit code 141. Right after that, another window popped up - Low Disk Space and said This computer has only 0 bytes disk space remaining.

Comment: You must use gpt partitioning for any drive over 2TiB. And if you want UEFI install you must use gpt partitioning. And with UEFI you must have an ESP - efi system partition. If you want the very old BIOS install then you need a bios_grub partition. UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace & http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation If no Windows skip Windows screens.

Comment: Also if Dell make sure you have drives set to AHCI, not RAID nor IDE. And some may have Intel SRT which makes drive look like it has RAID. http://askubuntu.com/questions/884991/ubuntu-16-10-dual-boot-error-grub-efi-amd64-signed-package-failed-to-install & https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN301754/how-to-install-ubuntu-and-a-recent-windows-operating-system-as-a-dual-boot-on-your-dell-pc?lang=EN

Comment: Thanks, oldfred - I just set the drive to AHCI (it was on RAID) and I partitioned the drive again and it worked! It looks OK and is using the entire drive which is what I wanted. I am doing updates now so I am good to go. My question can be closed. Thanks everyone! I have a lot to learn but it was fun - most of the time!

Comment: @oldfred Consider expanding your comments to a full answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was from oldfred: In the BIOS setting the SATA drive to AHCI and then re-partitioning the hard drive resolved the issue. Thanks to all who responded.

Comment: Please accept your answer by clicking the tick on the left.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution, and good luck with Ubuntu :-)

Comment: Sorry I didn't accept this answer sooner! I have been having fun with Ubuntu! I have been able to replace my win 10 system which was my main goal. Thanks to all for your help and sorry again for being late to accept!