# Requirements to install Ubuntu amd64 to a Dell XPS 15 (9560)?

Tags: boot, system-installation, graphics, dell

What requirements are there in order to install Ubuntu amd64 (any of the recent releases) as the only OS on a Dell 15 XPS (9560) with 32GB RAM and 1TB SSD?
What in particular is required for the BIOS and graphics?

Comment: Nothing "in particular is required for the BIOS and graphics". Ubuntu should run well on any contemporary PC.

Comment: Dell seems to need a few settings and UEFI & SSD firmware updates. Drives may be set to RAID even if only one drive, change to AHCI.  What video card? If nVidia you may need nomodeset until you are able to install nVidia driver from repository. Dell XPS 13 9560 install without issues
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2357321
Dell XPS 13 9360 16.04 worked after nvme firmware & BIOS update, 16.10 did not, new rEFInd for NVMe
http://askubuntu.com/questions/884991/ubuntu-16-10-dual-boot-error-grub-efi-amd64-signed-package-failed-to-install

Comment: Video card: NVIDIA(R) GeForce(R) GTX 1050 with 4GB GDDR5

Comment: Using AHCI, Secure boot disabled. System 16.04.3 or 17.04 installs, but runs into problems, e,g, after logon, no icons, no "status" bar, nothing can be done, except moving external mouse pointer. Hard reboot required. Recent install of 17.04 worked for some time. When removing autologin for the administrator and rebooting, the above problem occurred.

Comment: New attempt with a fresh ubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64 on USB. Got the window where to choose install and proceeded. Chose both to download ubuntu software and third-party software. Installation proceeded to the end, where you are presented with the windows and button "Reboot now". Clicking that caused not much to happen, and definitely no reboot. Rebooted hard, checked BIOS, no ubuntu entry, only a disk name in legacy mode. Changed UEFI to Legacy. Bootup displays a ubuntu screen, nothing more. No pointer. Nothing can be done and it stays so until rebooting hard.