# Problem with installation on new laptop (dualboot)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, laptop

I just recently got a new XPS13 for studying purposes(IT) and obviously want to have both Windows and Ubuntu installed.
Problem is, when i want to intall it in dualboot, the installation setup and GParted dont detect my SSD, and only read the USB drive, where the ISO file is located.
Partitions dont help the situation, various versions of Ubuntu dont either.

I really really want to keep Windows in my new machine so please help a noob out :D

here is some code you asked for:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lsblk -f

NAME   FSTYPE LABEL              UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
loop0  squash                                                         /rofs
sda    iso966 Ubuntu 17.10 amd64 2017-10-18-18-53-18-00               /cdrom
├─sda1 iso966 Ubuntu 17.10 amd64 2017-10-18-18-53-18-00               
└─sda2 vfat   Ubuntu 17.10 amd64 2D90-0993  


ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted -l
Warning: The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but
Linux says it is 512 bytes.
Ignore/Cancel?
```

Comment: is the ATA controler set for RAID instead of AHCI?

Comment: i dont even know, explain please

Comment: enter the system firmware settings by pressing a function key while booting. Usually it is F2,F10, or F12 but could be any. The interface varies by computer, but look for drive settings. IDE/RAID is an older drive control protocol. AHCI is a newer "smart" protocol. Some systems won't allow selection.

Comment: okay i will try setting it to RAID and see how it goes from there, thanks!

Comment: No you want AHCI. Dell XPS 13 9360 16.04 worked after nvme firmware & BIOS update, 16.10 did not, new rEFInd for NVMe
http://askubuntu.com/questions/884991/ubuntu-16-10-dual-boot-error-grub-efi-amd64-signed-package-failed-to-install

Comment: it should be set to AHCI for easiest ubuntu install. But if you change it Windows will have to be modified for it to boot (drivers added)

Comment: Could you please boot the Ubuntu installation medium, select the "Try Ubuntu" entry, open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T), run `sudo lsblk -f` and `sudo parted -l` and then [edit] your question to include their output? Thanks.

Comment: I edited the question.

my phisical disk info says:

size:   476.9GB
Status:     NON-RAID
Controller Type:   NVMe
Controller Interface:    PCIe

Comment: I also checked and I have the newest BIOS installed

Answer (score 0):

okay So i almost got it to work, everything was perfect and then I accidentally created a partition of my whole ssd with GParted and now my Windows is gone;/ any way to get it back?