# Dell XPS 15 9560 Dual Boot - Ubuntu partition only boots following Windows restart

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, dell

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 / Windows 10 to dual-boot on my Dell XPS 15 9560, however, there is an annoying peculiarity:

**Ubuntu only successfully boots following a Windows restart.**

On startup, Grub appears as follows:

[GRUB bootloader immediately after startup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yw0Fb.jpg)

You'll notice the multiple boot options for Windows 10 (ie. any of `Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi`, `Windows Boot UEFI loader`, `Windows Boot Manager`) and Ubuntu (ie. any of `Ubuntu` or `EFI/ubuntu/*`). I'm unfortunately not familiar with the cause for the various boot options but, in case this is related, it's worth attesting that, as [conventionally suggested](https://superuser.com/questions/265263/dual-booting-windows-and-linux-why-install-windows-first), I had indeed first installed Windows (via clean install) before proceeding to install the Ubuntu partition on my system.

From this GRUB boot loader interface, assuming that I had arrived from a hard power-on, Ubuntu fails to load properly and instead displays as follows:

[Ubuntu error on startup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5JZ6.jpg)

Alternatively, if I first enter my windows partition (e.g. from the above window, running `enter` -> `systemctl reboot` and selecting `Windows UEFI` from the GRUB menu) then restart from Windows, it is now possible to enter Ubuntu by selecting any of the Ubuntu GRUB options.

My system usage seems to function without errors via the above workflow, however, for obvious reasons, it is not the most convenient.

Comment: Other similar systems, perhaps a setting is mentioned that you need. Dell XPS 13 9560 install without issues
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2357321 & 
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_XPS_15_9560
Dell XPS 13 9360 16.04 worked after nvme firmware & BIOS update, 16.10 did not, new rEFInd for NVMe
http://askubuntu.com/questions/884991/ubuntu-16-10-dual-boot-error-grub-efi-amd64-signed-package-failed-to-install

Comment: So when you power on you have to start Windows first and then restart and then select Ubuntu. What happens if you restart from Ubuntu without powering off, can you select Ubuntu again?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix - just verified this: **yes**, restart from Ubuntu without powering off indeed allows me to select Ubuntu again

Comment: @oldfred - thanks for the reference material: I'll continue to look through these but don't yet seeing any settings that I'd missed during initial installation

Comment: It sounds like Windows is initializing hardware or firmware that Ubuntu isn't. I'm not sure where to start looking though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news! I found a solution.

Per the suggestion of @WinEunuuchs2Unix that

> "Windows is initializing hardware or firmware that Ubuntu isn't"

a likely culprit was [Windows 10 Hibernation](https://www.howtogeek.com/102897/whats-the-difference-between-sleep-and-hibernate-in-windows/).

Thus, [turning off Windows 10 Hibernation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/920730/how-to-disable-and-re-enable-hibernation-on-a-computer-that-is-running) was all I needed to solve the problem. Additionally, by accident, it solved a previously unresolved issue that Windows 10's clock was inaccurate following Ubuntu restart (this last step fixed the issue in addition to the steps described [here](https://windowsreport.com/fix-windows-10-clock/)).