# Failed 18.04.1 installation - The 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, 18.04, uefi

> The ' grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install into / target/.
>   Without the GRUB boot loader, the installed system will not boot.

This is the error I get every time I try to install 18.04. I have formatted the MBR and **C** drive of Windows and currently I have only `dev/sda` to install. I don't want to lose other data which I had in Windows 10.

What should be the status of legacy mode and secure boot while installing Ubuntu 18.04?

I see only `dev/sda` instead of `dev/sda2`, `dev/sda3`.

What should I do?

Comment: Pick one from https://askubuntu.com/questions/789998/16-04-new-installation-gives-grub-efi-amd64-signed-failed-installation-target https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056647/the-grub-efi-amd64-signed-package-failed-to-install-into-target-without-th https://askubuntu.com/questions/934415/ubuntu-16-04-grub-efi-amd64-signed-failed-to-install-into-target-error  But I found at least 25 similar

Comment: @PRATAP sorry, it's 18.04.1

Comment: "I don't want to loose other data which I had in Windows 10." And that's why you make a backup before messing with your system.

Comment: Thanks @Rinzwind . My previous installation had a virus. Therefore, I thought it was not safe to move files before checking to another PC. My best bet is installing Ubuntu, reviewing files and then move them. How can I achieve " bootable USB should have a GPT ". I am not skilled. If you don't mind, can you please tell me what I should do in a sentence or two ?

Comment: 2 sentences? Not really. But the 3 topics I posted in comments should be enough ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The point is that you need to have **EFI System Partition**. So create one with 512MB.
For detailed installation instructions check:
[Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Minimal Install Guide](https://linuxhint.com/ubuntu-18-04-lts-minimal-install-guide/)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82188/discussion-on-answer-by-alexandar-g-failed-18-04-1-installation).