# Missing dependancies for any program I try to install

Tags: package-management

So today it's Recoll, it says it's installed but it won't launch. When I try through the terminal it says

```
error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Widgets.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So I tried

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5-widgets
```

and get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libqt5-widgets
```

I haven't been able to install any new programs since I got **18.04** a month ago, some of them install and even launch but they never work, there is always something missing. I always get a message about some missing dependency.

I have all the repository boxes ticked in the settings.

I've tried apt-get update and apt-get upgrade

I've looked at threads with similar topics and no answer.

```
apt-cache policy recoll
recoll:
  Installed: 1.23.7-1
  Candidate: 1.23.7-1
  Version table:
 *** 1.23.7-1 500
        500 http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status


$ which recoll
/usr/bin/recoll
```

This happens no matter what program I try to install.

Thanks.

Comment: The library appears to be provided by package `libqt5widgets5`

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy recoll`, `which recoll`, `ldd $(which recoll)` and `ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5 | grep not` to the question.

Comment: Done! I meant to say this happens regardless of program...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the search on [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libQt5Widgets.so.5) you need to get `libqt5widgets5` package with

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5widgets5
```

Also for your information Recoll is [available in official repositories (in *universe* pocket)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=recoll) too and installable with

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get install recoll
```

---

To be completely sure that your system integrity is complete consider to use [debsums](https://askubuntu.com/q/57682/66509).

Comment: Yes I got it from the official repositories, I get everything from there, but no matter what I get from the official repositories there are missing dependencies. So yeah, "'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.
"

Comment: When i did that it said "libqt5widgets5 is already the newest version", and I still get the same error message when i try to open recoll. I don't understand what the link you sent me wants me to do?

Comment: Ah ha ok i figured out what the debsums stuff was about, sorry it took me a while. Yes, that worked, sorted out all the missing dependencies and all the programs I've been trying to install are working now. Thank you!