# Install MV without installation

Tags: command-line, kubuntu, error-handling, mv

I have the problem that whenever I want to Install something, there is this lovely error:

```
/usr/sbin/update-initramfs: 158: /usr/sbin/update-initramfs: mv: not found
```

I could trace this error back, and the problem is actually this one:

```
Command 'mv' not found
```

Now I have the quite interesting task to install the mv-command without being able to install any new Packages. Using Dolphin on Kubuntu 18.4 (I guess it is that one since I didn't do any updates) I am able to copy files, and if someone was able to give me some kind of source file for the mv command, I could "simply" change the update-initramfs file in order to install coreutils which then would "repair" my not actually broken ramfs.

Any Help would be cool, a friend already told me that I would have to completely reinstall the system, if it is possible to prevent that from happening, I would very much appreciate it.

And I guess it is possible to copy with root privileges, but I haven't tried that yet.

Thanks for everybody trying to help.

Edit: in /bin there isn't a file called coreUtils or something like that, I don't know if there should be

```
ls: cannot access '/bin/mv': No such file or directory


/usr/local/sbin /usr/local/bin /usr/sbin /usr/bin /sbin /bin /usr/games /usr/local/games /snap/bin
```

Comment: `mv` should be in the folder `/bin/`.

Comment: Can you add to your question the output of `echo $PATH`, and the output of `ls /bin/mv`

Comment: This may be symptom of other missing files or other issues. `mv` is such a fundamental part of the system I can't imagine it just vanishing on its own.

Comment: @N0rbert thats kinda embarassing now, a simlpe --reinstall actually "did the magick", haven't thought about it before.

Answer (score 3):

Norbert pointed it out, [this askubuntu Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57682/find-and-reinstall-packages-with-corrupted-files-without-breaking-anything) totally helped, I simmply needed to use `sudo apt install --reinstall coreutils`, and now everything works again...
Thanks Norbert!
I don't know if it works that way, but if it gets the points post your thing as an Answer, then I can (I believe) set it as the working answer.