# apt is complaining about held packages but there are no packages held back

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management

I saw during boot an error with something from selinux. So I searched for related packages on my System and found

```
libselinux1
```

I start a simulation with apt.

```
apt --dry-run purge libselinux1
NOTE: This is only a simulation!
      apt needs root privileges for real execution.
      Keep also in mind that locking is deactivated,
      so don't depend on the relevance to the real current situation!
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libxft2 : Depends: libfontconfig1 (>= 2.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Realy apt?

```
 apt-cache policy libfontconfig1 
libfontconfig1:
  Installed: 2.12.6-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 2.12.6-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 2.12.6-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

And

```
 apt-cache policy libxft2
libxft2:
  Installed: 2.3.2-1
  Candidate: 2.3.2-1
  Version table:
 *** 2.3.2-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Try update.

```
 sudo apt update
[sudo] password for alex: 
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                           
Hit:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                        
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]                                                         
Hit:5 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                            
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]                                 
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]     
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages [597 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates i386 Contents (deb) [34.1 MB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages [984 kB]                                            
Fetched 36.0 MB in 24s (1506 kB/s)                                                                                                
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

Note no packages from winehq and  from teejee2008 only uuku on my system.

Did I oversee something important?

No package in unclean state.

```
dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii'
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                  Version                                     Architecture Description
+++-=====================================-===========================================-============-===============================================================================
```

This Error is misleading. Some packages need libselinux1 like coreutils or smartmontools.

Comment: I tried to execute your command on clean fully upgraded 18.04 LTS system and it says that 1001 package will be removed. Then added two repositories (as you wrote), but still can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Something is broken on my system. md5sum had a lot of warnings about missing files and not readable files. Maybe because of broken RAM on my old laptop. Never mind.

Comment: About RAM - reboot to GRUB and select Memtest from it to check. You should not have red otutput here (it indicates errors). About debsums - you can try to [reinstall broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/a/392326/66509).

Comment: thank you @N0rbert in my case it doesn't not make sense to repair ubuntu. I have to replace it with an 64-bit ubuntu release. `uname -a
Linux beelzemon 4.15.0-66-generic #75-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 1 05:22:52 UTC 2019 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux`

Comment: OK, but anyway check RAM with Memtest to ensure that it operates normally :)

Comment: It was my old laptop, which has error in one ram. Not my current.