# Ubuntu/Windows computer boots directly into Ubuntu bypassing Dual-Boot w/o allowing access to BIOS

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, usb, bios

This is not really a question, it is more of an observation. I could not find an answer to my specific problem and stumbled on the solution after many hours of trial and error. I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my Asus Laptop along side Windows 10. Things were running smoothly until I plugged in the USB Wireless Mouse dongle. After doing that, the computer would bypass the dual boot screen and boot directly into Ubuntu and not give me the ability to boot into Windows or enter BIOS update no matter how hard I tried. After unplugging the mouse dongle, everything returned to normal, the dual-boot menu returned and I was also able to enter the BIOS setup by pressing F2.

Edit - 2020/12/16 - As it turns out, my computer works just fine now with the mouse dongle plugged in. I ran several instances of boot-repair that did not correct the problem. Then I ran some scripts from this question in askubuntu - [Find (and reinstall) packages with corrupted files (without breaking anything)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57682/find-and-reinstall-packages-with-corrupted-files-without-breaking-anything) to repair some corrupted files in install packages and another boot-repair and unplugged the mouse dongle and the computer booted normally. So I guess either repairing the corrupted files or the boot-repair or both corrected the problem and not unplugging the mouse dongle. Thank-you all for your assistance.

Comment: That's weird, at least you should be able to see the BIOS setup. Can you tell us what is the model number of your Asus machine?

Comment: It's model number U50F.

Comment: No matter what devices you connect, system should still be able to show up BIOS setup when you press F2, DEL or which ever is specified for your model. As someone commented below, it has something to do with the boot order but most possibly a bug in the BIOS which does not attend F2, DEL keystrokes when the USB device is connected. I hope Asus forum/technical support would be able to help you further. You may try different things like using a different wireless mouse for example. Unplug the dongle and get into the BIOS and look closely for any setting related to USB, BOOT etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling it may have something to do with the boot order, and you might be able to fix is just by changing a couple boot order settings. (Probably moving USB boot below HDD or SDD boot)

Lastly, you may have tried this, but F2 or some other top row key may be able to work.

Comment: I tried several keys to no avail.

Comment: Isn't there an option to boot into BIOS from grub?

Answer (score 0):

Watch when your computer posts at the very start of booting. There will be a very brief, very brief, line across the bottom that says "Use F2" or "Use F7" to enter Boot Options, or into Bios Configuration. (It can be any of the F-keys, but usually F2, F7, F8 F10, etc.) Just watch the screen careful during post/boot/startup when the screen is still black and white.

When you enter into the BIOS Configuration, use the arrow key and navigate to the right tab where it says "BOOT OPTIONS" or "BOOT ORDER". Go there, hit Enter and use the arrow keys to move your BOOT Devices/Priorities up, or down. Put the device that has your bootloader (GRUB) at the top of the list. Then go to "SAVE CHANGES AND EXIT" and hit Enter and then, "YES" to save and exit.

That should do it. There are probably thousands of videos on YouTube and probably a handful that are decent, to show visually what to do. It is really easy and you should be done in just a few minutes.

Good Luck... you won't need it for this. It is Easy!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. On my computer the time to press the F2 was when the ASUS Splash screen appeared. But when I was having the issues, it never appeared. My work around is to plug in the wireless mouse dongle after I boot and now everything works fine.